# Is there a way to create an Excel data connection to an Outlook folder?

Tags: excel, ms-access, outlook

Is there a way to create a data connection to an export of an Outlook folder's contents?

Currently, I use Microsoft Access to import an Outlook folder into a database, then I export it to a .csv file.

Is it possible to save a few steps and just have Excel import the data directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Access OLEDB provider to create a recordset, and then import that to your worksheet.

See the following sample code

```
Public Sub ADOOutlook()
    Dim conn As Object
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Outlook 9.0;MAPILEVEL=%email-address%|;PROFILE=Outlook;TABLETYPE=0;TABLENAME=Inbox;COLSETVERSION=12.0;DATABASE=C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp\"
    Dim rs As Object
    Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM Inbox;")
    Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
End Sub
```

Replace %username% with your username (or choose a different temporary location), and replace %email-address% with your mail account.

Note that this code is dependent on your outlook setup. You can generate your own connection string by linking the desired outlook folder in access to a linked table, and then using `CurrentDb.TableDefs("MyLinkedTable").Connect` to print the connection string (append `Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;` to the start of it)